# Moved Elastic Beanstalk server to a different region and can no longer access s3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services

I recently moved my Elastic Beanstalk instances from east1 to east2. But there are a bunch of private buckets still in east1. Now my code throws errors and refuses to connect to the buckets across the region. I get this error

```
s3.list_objects(bucket:'mp3list') *** Aws::S3::Errors::PermanentRedirect Exception
```

Is there a way to give my Elastic Beanstalks that are behind a VPC in a different region access to private buckets in a different region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You do have access* to the buckets but you’re not handling the **HTTP Redirect** correctly.

If it worked correctly while in `us-east-1` I guess your app accesses `https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-bucket/..`. And now that it's running in `us-east-2` it probably tries to access `https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/your-bucket/..`. However because the bucket is not in the `us-east-2` region you get HTTP Redirect to `https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-bucket/..` Your app must be able to handle this redirect.

What language and library you use to access the buckets? If you used the official AWS SDKs (e.g. `boto3` in case of Python) this should work without any extra effort. If you’ve coded your own S3 library you will have to add the redirect handling to it.

Hope that helps :)